# How can I stop executing the rest of a method at some point inside the method?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is a command which would have the same function as `exit`.

So, for instance:

```
if (Average < 35)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you failed");
    **EXIT**
}

if (Average >= 75)
{
    lblOutput.Text += Name +" " + Surname + ", " + "your average was: " + Average + ", you shall recieve a bursary!";
}
else
    lblOutput.Text += Name +" " + Surname + ", " + "your average was: " + Average + ", you shall not revieve a bursary!";
```

Even if the average is lower than 35, the script will carry on going and the `lblOutput` will still say `You shall not receive a bursary.` while it should just show the `MessageBox` and not do anything with the label.

Could someone explain how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to return from the function or terminate the process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `return;` to stop the execution path.

Comment: that won't "Carry on" to the lblOutput code (as OP mentioned in question).

Comment: @BradChristie think you misread like I did initially, the OP says the code *currently* does that, but they don't want it to.

Comment: Ah, touche. Yea, must be a) not enough coffee, or b) a confusing question. (I'm leaning more toward the former)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that current code reside in a method with return type `void`, you can simply use `return;`

```
if (Average < 35)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you failed");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to using `return` to exit early, you could write your `if` statements in such a way that it naturally follows that code path

```
if (Average >= 75)
{
    lblOutput.Text += Name +" " + Surname + ", " + "your average was: " + Average + ", you shall recieve a bursary!";
}
else if (Average >= 35)
{
    lblOutput.Text += Name +" " + Surname + ", " + "your average was: " + Average + ", you shall not revieve a bursary!";
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("you failed");
}
```

For me this is better from a readability point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead or return just do

```
if()
{
}
else
{
}
```